# Make the local variable to global in extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs, global-variables

How to make local variable to global?

```
Ext.define('A.view.Management', {
extend: 'Ext.container.Container',

requires: [
    'A.store.Management',
],

border: false,
chart: null,

hrer: [],   

initComponent: function () {
    var me = this;

    me.jobStore2 = Ext.create('O2a.store.Management');


    Ext.Ajax.request({
        url: utils.createUrl('api', 'ard-read'),
        async: true,

        callback: function(opts, success, response) {
            try {

                if (success) {
                    var output = App.decodeHttpResp(response.responseText);
                    const data = output.data;

                    let myArr = [];
                    data.map((date) => 
                    myArr = Object.keys(date).filter(key => key != 'DATE'));
                    me.hrer =myArr;

                    console.log(me.hrer);

                    if (output.success) {
                        //return output.success;
                    } else {
                        //return output.error;
                    }
                } else {
                    //return 'Unknown Reason';
                }
            } catch (ex) {
                //return ex;
            }
        }
    });
console.log(me.hrer);
```

I want to take hrer array to outside. When I console.log it outside the ajax request I am getting an empty array which I have defined as globally. I couldn't pass the values which getting inside the ajax request to outside

Comment: By outside you mean outside component or outside Ajax callback?

Comment: outside the ajax call back

Comment: Is it possible to do?

Comment: `me.hrer` should be accessible inside component everywhere, within ajax callback as well as outside.
The fact that you are getting an empty array, might be because you are reading it before ajax callback has called.

Comment: Then is it possible to take that out of the component

Comment: Yes, a dirty and quick way is to use `window.hrer`. Clean way is to use a shared singleton store. I'll also post an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ExtJS 4, we used to do:

```
Ext.define('A.store.SharedData', { 
    singleton: true, 

    foo: 'bar', 
    johnDoeAge: 42,
    hrer: []
});
```

Then require it in whichever component you want to use and consume it like:

```
Ext.define('A.view.Management', {
    extend: 'Ext.container.Container',

    requires: [
        'A.store.Management',
        'A.store.SharedData'
    ],




    initComponent: function () {
        var me = this;
        A.store.SharedData.hrer = [1, 2, ...];
        ...
    }
    ...
});
```